# Debug step by step loopback Api

Tags: node.js, debugging, loopback

I'm trying to debug a loopback application with the $slc debug command.
When I run the command, the application start to listening in the port 5858 and I can debug step by step the application, the problem is that I can't call any API end point to debug it.
Any idea if it is posible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you start debugging with slc debug you need to continue in the debugger (to start the loopback server) and put a breakpoint where you want to break. If you have a custom function/API - then you would put the breakpoint there.  If you want to break at the point an API gets called that's out of the box loopback, you can [override the method for debugging purposes and call the original method](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback/issues/443).

I [created a tutorial video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kthQssL_vFk) that includes info on how to override methods and also some various ways to debug.  See the description of the video for quick links.

Comment: Thank you very much! The tutorial is amazing.